# Show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{4^n} h\left(2^n P\right)$ exists

Tags: limits, number-theory, elliptic-curves, cauchy-sequences, rational-numbers

This question comes from Rational Points on Elliptic Curves (Silverman & Tate) exercise 3.3(a).

> $3.3$. Let $C$ be a rational cubic curve given by the usual Weierstrass equation.
> Prove that for any rational point $P \in C(\mathbb{Q})$, the limit
> $$\hat{h}(P)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{4^n} h\left(2^n P\right)$$
> exists. The quantity $\hat{h}(P)$ is called the canonical height of $P$.

Note that the height of $x$ is $H(x)=H\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\max \{|m|,|n|\}$ and $h(P)=\log H(P)$

It gave a hint to suggest showing the sequence is Cauchy, so here is my attempt:

We wish to show that, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $m, n > N$ then $$\left|4^{-n}h(2^nP) - 4^{-m}h(2^mP)\right|<\varepsilon.$$ Write $P = x/y$ so we have

$$\left|4^{-n}h(2^n\frac x y) - 4^{-m}h(2^m\frac x y)\right|.$$

Now, I'm not sure how to proceed but my best idea is that because $e^{\varepsilon}$ can be made arbitrarily small just like $\varepsilon$ itself, we can raise everything to the power of $e$ and get rid of small $h$. Is this the right direction?

Comment: Look up the canonical height functions in books on elliptic curves to see how the Cauchy condition is verified in those cases, e.g., Silverman Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Prop. 9.1, Chapter VIII.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but that book this book is meant as a *precursor* to Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves and I’m sure the authors have a solution in mind that doesn’t require a graduate level text

Comment: I know that, but I was not suggesting you need to look at lots of things in that book. See just one page in it for *inspiration*. Not everything in a grad-level book has to need a high level of background in order to get anything out of it.  And since you're asking how to go about showing a sequence is Cauchy, I pointed you to a place where exactly that kind of thing is done. Another reference is Section 3.1 of Chapter 3 of Serre's "Lectures on the Mordell-Weil Theorem". That book too is meant for grad students in general, but others can get something out of reading a *particular* page in it.

Comment: You probably understand this, but something in your notation leaves a doubt. So just to be on the safe side: I'm fairly sure that you are supposed to start with a rational point $P=(x,y)\in C$, then calculate the sequence of points $P_n=[2^n]P$, where on the right hand side I use square brackets to emphasize that you use the elliptic curve addition. In other words $P_0=P$, $P_n=P_{n-1}+P_{n-1}$. And then with $P_n=(x_n,y_n)$ with $x_n,y_n\in\Bbb{Q}$ you use the vector version of the height: $H(P_n)=\max\{H(x_n),H(y_n)\}$ et cetera.

Comment: Maybe that’s something I missed. Why do we have to use the duplication formula for P if we are given just one point?

Comment: That $2^nP$ refers to the point $P+P+P+\cdots+P$, where there are $2^n$ terms, and $+$ is the addition of points on the elliptic curve. Basically you need to use the duplication map $n$ times to get the point $2^nP$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go ahead and answer my question since I now see how to do it.

We will show that the sequence is Cauchy. We (I) have already shown that there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $Q \in E(\bar{K})$,
$$\left|h(2 Q)-4 h(Q)\right| \leq C.$$

Now we will show that the series is a telescoping sum (how clever!). For integers $N \geqslant M \geqslant 0$ we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\mid 4^{-N} h\left(2^N P\right) - 4^{-M} h({\left.2^M P\right) \mid} &= \left|\sum_{n = M}^{N-1} 4^{-n - 1} h\left(2^{n+1} P\right) - 4^{-n} h\left(2^n P\right)\right| \\
&\leqslant \sum_{n=M}^{N-1} 4^{-n-1}\left|h\left(2^{n+1} P\right) - 4 h\left(2^n P\right)\right| \\
& \leqslant \sum_{n=M}^{N-1} 4^{-n-1} C \quad \text { taking } Q=2^n P \\
& \leqslant 4^{-M} C.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, the sequence $4^{-N} h\left(2^N P\right)$ is Cauchy, and thus the limit exists!

Thanks to user KCd for pointing me in the right direction.